# How to open a new window in pyside

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, pyside

I am a beginner in Python as well as pyside. I have a .ui file and I want to open it as a second window on clicking a button in main window. I used this code but it closes the main window perhaps because of "self". Please help me out.

```
class PhoneBook:

   def __init__(self):
        loader = QUiLoader();       
        file = QFile("PhoneBook.ui");   
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly);  
        self.ui = loader.load(file);    
        file.close();           
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add);

  def __del__ ( self ):
        self.ui = None;

  def add(self):
        loader1 = QUiLoader();      
        file1 = QFile("Add.ui");    
        file1.open(QFile.ReadOnly); 
        self.ui = loader1.load(file1);  
        file1.close();          
        self.ui.show();

  def show(self):
        self.ui.show();
```

Comment: I don't have working knowledge on PySide, but your guess is close to the truth, in your add() method you're essentially overwriting the object variable `self.ui` with a newly loaded ui file. If you intend to add another window, spawn another by creating a local variable `ui2` or another object variable `self.ui2`, depends on what you need to do with the second one.

Comment: Thanks woozyking. It really worked. But just another noob question. How to make a new dialog using QDialog ? Means that i want to make a new dialog in the add method without using .ui file.

Comment: Glad that helped. As I said, I have no working knowledge of PySide. Check their official documentation http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/ for in-depth reference. I'm sure there are ways to manipulate UI elements in a programmatic way without using such .ui files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm noob too. About how to make dialog, I think your point is input dialog where you want to enter data for that phonebook. The easiest way I found is such :

```
txtLabel = "Put some value into dialog"
inputText, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Dialog Name", txtLabel)
if ok:
    print ".........."
    print inputText
```

...and that's for the simplest dialog for some string input (QInputDialog). If you need more demanding dialog (and you will, sooner or later), you should use QDialog base class. In that case what exactly you want to put into it, how it will looks like and everything about it's behaviour. On PySide [DOCS](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QDialog.html?highlight=qdialog#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QDialog.DialogCode) almost everything is nice explained.

Comment: Thanks Alex for answering. The link is surely very informative.